# Fragments on Android 1.6 with compatability package

Tags: android-layout, android

basically i have an app that should change according to whether it is run on a tablet or a phone. My main activity as a menu (list of buttons) very much like figure 1 on ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and i want to achieve the same look on the tablet device.

Now basically I keep the low api requirement of my current app (7) but have it automatically use fragments if run in a table that has the higher api level. Ijust want to have the app availible to the most device downwards
So as far as i understand it, i have to have one big .java file with all my previously seperated activities and put them all in fragments that are not visible until one clicks on the appropriate button.
All this has to be in one xml layout file in the xhdpi folder so the tablet uses it?

Can you tell me if im on the right track or if there is a shortcut to speed that up a little?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fragments for all your classes including those that will be run on 1.6, that will help with the re-use.

This video from Google IO 2011 will explain it for you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y

Comment: would it be possible to get code for the java and xml files for a very simple layout of just having to fragments right next to each other both occupying let's say half the screen? i think i could manage to extrapolate from that what i needed but all the tutorials i found online dive into super complicated in depth things to include lots of different things that i don't need in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with compatibility package for Android 1.6

[Force close with View Swiping with ViewPager on Android 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7168894/563306)